# Этимология слова прах

Tags: этимология

Интересно было бы узнать о происхождении слова **прах** (по звучанию оно явно не славянское).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По звучанию - старославянизм - неполногласие -ра-, а по-русски порох-оро-

Др.-р. порохъ - "пыль", а в ст.-слав.  (церковнославянском) прах -пыль, тлен, а уже потом -останки, пепел. Так что в русский пришло из церковнославянского. А корень праславянский - *porхъ - пыль от индоевроп.* pers - брызгать, осыпать.

Так что и перхоть, и порхать, и поршень, и пороша, и порошок - всё оттуда.